# Handle return value of background Task - Async Await

Tags: c#, asp.net, async-await, httpcontext

I have a long running method that I wish to run on a background thread. The method uses the MailChimp api to subscribe a long list of email addresses.

I don't want my "Web Forms" app to hang whilst this task runs but I do want to handle any exceptions that occur.

We call the following method to get things running:

```
ExecuteAsyncBatchRegistration(mcitems);
```

Below is the method we just called:

```
public async Task ExecuteAsyncBatchRegistration(List<MailChimpItem> mcitems)
{
    GenericResponse response = new GenericResponse();

    await Task.Run(() =>
    {
        response = ExecuteBatchRegistration(mcitems);

        if (response.Success == false)
        {
            ErrorHandler.WriteError(response.Exception);
        }
    });
}
```

The method call **ErrorHandler.WriteError()** uses **HttpContext.Current** so that it can tell me the page URL, IP address etc. However, in this instance **HttpContext.Current** is NULL.

I can resolve this by changing the method as follows:

```
public async Task ExecuteAsyncBatchRegistration(List<MailChimpItem> mcitems)
{
    GenericResponse response = new GenericResponse();

    response = await Task<GenericResponse>.Run(() =>
    {
        return ExecuteBatchRegistration(mcitems);
    });

    if (response.Success == false)
    {
        ErrorHandler.WriteError(response.Exception);
    }
}
```

The problem with the latter version of the method is that the app hangs: it doesn't appear to run asynchronously in the background.

How can I run this method asynchronously and retain HttpContent.Current?

Comment: Do you care about the return value or only to catch and log exceptions it might throw?

Comment: If you do not want your web form to hang, ie. you want to return the result to the user and offload the process then you need to capture the data you need from the Http context and pass those to your offloaded task **and do not access the http context again in that task because there will not be one**. If you want the http context to be available then you cannot end the request which means the form will "hang". The only other good alternative to keep the http context is to make the call using javascript. Normally I suggest not running it at all in the web context but offload it to a service.

Comment: The return value "GenericReponse" simply contains an Exception and results message. I need to process this. I can be done anywhere though so long as the whole task is done asynchronously. The return value is purely for my benefit, not the end-user - they don't need the return value.

Comment: ok Igor, so I guess I can pass the HttpContext to the ErrorHandler?

Comment: `so I guess I can pass the HttpContext to the ErrorHandler` <= Nope. There will not be a HttpContext, it is gone. As soon as you return a Response the HttpContext is not there so do not try to capture it. Instead take what you might need from it (user info, ip, whatever) and pass that as state to your long running process for whatever purposes you need it for (logging, actions, anything).

Comment: ASP.NET was designed to serve requests. As soon as you try to do work *outside* of a request, then you're trying to pound a screw with a hammer, and you *will* run into problems. The proper solution is to use a distributed architecture (see [my blog](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2014/06/fire-and-forget-on-asp-net.html)).

Comment: Ok guys. Thanks for the suggestions. I think the best way forward, considering the size of the issue, is to simply pass the required fields to the ErrorHandler, or, do without that data contained in the HttpContext.

Comment: @David - correct, you can copy the state of those fields and pass it to your off loaded Task so the error handler can do something with that state. The limitation is that the error handler cannot return any type of response/notification to the caller using the `HttpContext`. You could get around this by implementing server to client communication using something like websockets or SignalR

Answer (score 1):

If you do not want your web form to hang (ie. you want to return the result to the user and offload the process) then you need to capture the data you need from the HttpContext and pass that to your offloaded long running Task. Do not access the `HttpContext` again in that Task because there will not be one. If you want the `HttpContext` to be available then you cannot end the request which means the form will "hang" and you do your processing on the Request thread. The only other good alternative to keep the HttpContext without making the user's web browser hang is to make the call using javascript. Normally I suggest not running it at all in the web context but offload it to a service or use something like HangFire but both of these have the same limitation that you cannot communicate with any type of `HttpContext`, you have to gather the state and pass it to the off loaded Task.

Comment: just be aware the thread might be killed after x seconds. windows service might be a better option

Comment: @Steve - agree 100%. If the task itself is important (*ie. it matters if it completes*) then it should not be executing on IIS thread because there is no guarantee that the task can/will run to completion.